# where to declare session_start if multiple files are included?

Tags: php

I have a doubt regarding php session variable declaration.

I have two php files. 1. head.php 2. body.php

**head.php**

```
session_start();
$id = $_Session['id'];
$name = $_Session['name'];
some other text like include js include css etc.
```

**body.php**

```
include 'head.php';
echo $id;
echo $uid;
```

is this correct? or do i need to add `session_start();` in **body.php** file as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You do not need to call the function again after you have called it in your header file.

And Oh, it is  `$_SESSION` , not `$_Session`

> where to declare session_start if multiple files are included?

Before you send **any output** to the browser. Nothing else matters. There can be hundreds of PHP code lines before that as long as they don't send any output you can call `session_start();` after that.

Obviously you will not have SESSION values before that :)

> Please elaborate i didn't understand

Don't `echo` or print etc anything before calling `session_start()`, not even outside PHP tags. Don't place any html or blank spaces before the PHP tags either. Absolutely nothing should be sent to browser before you call that function.

Wrong usage

```
<html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Right Usage

```
<?php
blahblahblah();   // or nothing
session_start();
echo "<html>";
?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate i didn't understand.

Comment: wrong. if you include f1.php and f1.php does session_start(), then you include f2.php and f2.php also does session_start() , you will get an error/warning that session is already started. unless you're hiding them with error_reporting() ofc

Comment: @hanshenrik Calling `session_start();` two times does not overwrite anything. `session_start — Start new or resume existing session` And no one suggested them to use it twice either.

Comment: You don't need to add `session_start();` in `body.php` if you included `head.php`.

Comment: @HankyPanky "do i need to add session_start(); in body.php file as well",  "Before you send any output to the browser. Nothing else matters", yeah, 1 thing matters, whether or not session_start() is already called. <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1'); session_start();session_start();

Comment: Nope even that does not matter. But yeah, you read the last line of the OP and i read the subject so our wording differs `where to declare session_start if multiple files are included?` So i can clearly understand the argument.

Comment: And in no way this answer suggests using the function twice.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are including your head.php in many php files you should check session first and then start session. otherwise you will get error.

```
     if(session_id())
 {
      // session has been started
 }
 else
 {
      // session has NOT been started
      session_start();
 }
```

Your current code is ok, session start should be in head.php itself